# Make a delayed check on @Input() array length

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm having a Component that uses an @Input() ids: string[] = []; variable that I having a check on the DOM if length is equal to 1.

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let id of ids" [expanded]="ids.length === 1">
...
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Then I append to the ids input from my parent component with ids.push(id) from a rest call that could take some time between responses.

This makes the site to show the mat-expansion-panel as expanded for a fraction of a second (depends on the response) and then collapse it again if there's more than one id. This is a unwanted behavior.

I don't know how to send the complete list at once (without pushing into it) after each id is fetched, since it all calls in a lot of nestled subscriptions rest calls.

Comment: I tried with a setTimeout with some time, but it make the site to expand the panel sometimes (depending on how fast the response is), and with a long delay. Not a solution that I want.

Comment: Not sure to understand what the problem is. `[expanded]="ids.length === 1"` doesn't work as expected. You know why ?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to have the data resolved first? And then show the expansion panel? Set off some flag when the subscription is complete and then show expansion panel etc.

Comment: I'll try to flag it when the subscription is complete. This could solve everything! I'll be back.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I'll show my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by having a flag that tells the component if all ids have a completed subscription.

**ParentComponent**

```
@Component({
  ...
  template: `
    <child-component [ids]="ids" [idsFinished]="idsCounter === 0">
    </child-component>
  `,
  ...
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  ids: string[] = [];
  idsCounter: number;
  ...
  private getIds(): void {
    this.getResourcesService().subscribe(resourcesResult => {
      this.idsCounter = resourcesResult.length;
      resourcesResult.forEach(resource => {
        this.getIdService(resource).subscribe(idResult => {
          this.ids.push(idResult);
          this.idsCounter--;
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**ChildComponent**

```
@Component({
  ...
  template: `
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let id of ids" [expanded]="ids.length === 1 && idsFinished"> 
      ...
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  `,
  ...
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() ids: string[] = [];
  @Input() idsFinished = false;
}
```